# Pandas DataFrame - select rows that match one of many conditions

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I want to select part of the dataframe, where the value in one particular column is one of multiple values.

What I do now is

```
idx = my_df['Column'].apply(lambda z: z in selected_items)
new_df = my_df[idx]
```

Is there a better way to achieve this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This should work?

```
new_df = my_df[my_df['Column'].isin(selected_items)]
```

Comment: Thanks. Before I accept your answer, how about the case when len(selected_items)==1, i.e. I have only a single item to match to?

Comment: @BaronYugovich for single matches you can use `new_df = my_df[my_df['Column'] == some_val]`

Comment: Also if your list contains a single item `isin` will still work

Answer (score 1):

Use [`isin`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.isin.html#pandas.Series.isin):

```
new_df = my_df[idx].isin(selected_items)
```

example:

```
In [579]:

df = pd.DataFrame({'a': [0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7]})
​
df
Out[579]:
   a
0  0
1  1
2  2
3  3
4  4
5  5
6  6
7  7
In [581]:

df[df['a'].isin([3,5,6])]
Out[581]:
   a
3  3
5  5
6  6
```

Another method is [`query`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.query.html#pandas.DataFrame.query):

```
In [582]:

df.query('a in [3,5,6]')
Out[582]:
   a
3  3
5  5
6  6
```